# Smooth out a single sharp corner in a function in Matlab

Tags: matlab, filtering, smoothing

So I want to smooth out Sharkfin signal at the point where it goes down and at the point where it goes up. As shown in the figure below, the Sharkfin waveform has sharp fall and rise at time 2 sec and 4 seconds:

[image: As shown in the figure below, the Sharkfin waveform has sharp fall and rise at time 1 sec and 2 seconds]

Any idea on how to round of that area so that it is smooth in that section so that it looks something like this:

[image: Smooth corner]

Comment: So you are looking for an algorithm to detect sharp corners in a signal and round them off. Have you found one?

Comment: Note that your usage of [`convex`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function) is probably wrong. Smoothing the corner will not make it more convex.

Comment: More than an algorithm, a step is good enough. I have an idea a moving average filter around the sharp rise and fall might work. But I was looking for some help from here. Or some help in implementing the filter only on a small section of the curve.

Comment: @m7913d Will change

Comment: Is it a problem if we change the other regions very slightly too? Otherwise, using a filter has the risk to introduce discontinuities at your filtering boundaries.

Comment: I've provided three suitable duplicate links above to address your problem.  The first one is a more general case where the time axis is not monotonically increasing in the positive direction.  The second one is most likely what you are looking for as time is only moving forward.  The third one is just for good measure.

Comment: @rayryeng Your provided solutions do not handle the case of only smoothing at specific locations, which seems to be the case here.

Comment: @m7913d Provided that the density of points in the interpolation is large enough, the areas that are being smoothed out shouldn't make a difference and only the points that are quite sharp would change.  However, if the OP explicitly says that the above doesn't work, I'll consider reopening.

Comment: I believe the duplicates are not answering the question (not even close), and vote to re-open.

Comment: @Floris Noted. I'll reopen.

Answer (score 1):

There are two separate things here - how do you detect a sharp transition, and how do you filter it.

Let's take these in turn.

A sharp transition is characterized by a large curvature - we can easily detect this by taking the `diff` of the input curve. Using the second parameter = 2 takes `diff` twice and results in something "like" the second derivative - but it's offset by one. So when we find points where the `diff(sharkfin,2)` is large, we need to offset by 1 to get the corner points.

Next, the smoothing itself. There are many techniques - I show a simple convolution with a box function. Doing this twice gives a smoothed version of the input. By picking the original "far from the discontinuity" and the filtered version "close to the discontinuity" we get exactly what you were asking for. If you wanted, you could "blend" the points - using a weighted version of filtered and unfiltered depending on how close you were to the corner points. I didn't show that explicitly but it should be easy to see how to expand the code I already wrote:

```
% generate a "shark fin" function:
fin = exp(-linspace(0,4,60));
shark = [fin (1-fin+fin(end))];
shark = repmat(shark, [1 3]);
D2 = diff(shark, 2);
roundMe = find(abs(D2)>0.1*max(D2))+1; % offset by 1 because second derivative

figure; 
subplot(3,1,1)
plot(shark); title 'shark plot'
hold on;
plot(roundMe, shark(roundMe),'r*')
legend('input','corners found')

% take N points on either side of the sharp corners:
N = 3;

% boxplot filtered version of the curve
boxFilt = ones(1, 2*N+1)/(2*N+1);
smoothShark1 = convn(shark, boxFilt, 'same'); % box plot

% second filter - smoother
smoothShark2 = convn(smoothShark1, boxFilt, 'same');


% plot the filtered results:
subplot(3,1,2)
plot(shark)
hold on
plot(smoothShark1);
hold on
plot(smoothShark2);
xlim([114 126])
ylim([0.8,1.1])
legend('original','box','box x2')
title 'smoothed everywhere'

% Now apply filtering only to points near the discontinuity
smoothMe = zeros(size(shark));
smoothMe(roundMe)=1;
smoothMe = convn(smoothMe, boxFilt, 'same');
smoothMe(smoothMe>0)=1; % this finds N points on either side of the corner

subplot(3,1,3)
plot(shark)
finalPlot=shark;
hold on
smoothIndx = find(smoothMe);
finalPlot(smoothIndx)=smoothShark2(smoothIndx);
plot(finalPlot,'g')
plot(smoothIndx, finalPlot(smoothIndx), 'r*')
xlim([114 126])
ylim([0.8,1.1])
legend('original','smoothed','changed')
title 'smoothed only near discontinuity'
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a ton for this answer. I modified and used it accordingly. Works really well :)